# missing ibd files

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6, partitioning, ibdata

I'm running mysql 5.6.  For reasons entirely my own fault, I've got some missing ibd that make up partitions for several tables.

When I try to mysql I get the following messages for the missing tables/partitions:

> 2018-10-24 01:41:06 3895 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table DATABASE/TABLE/PARTITION in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 16080, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.

I don't really want those partitions back as they contain old data that we don't want any more.  Is there any way to tell mysql that those partitions are gone, or to remove them from mysql's expected partition list.  Or is there any other way to fix this without a restore?